# Select folder to save without macro when user cancels dialog box

Tags: vba, excel

my code prompts user to save the current file as a macro free file, the problem is that if the user hits cancel then i get an error. i need my code to start over when the user hits cancel. so it would be best if a message box pops up and says please select location to save file and then the dialog box pops up again so the user can select where to save file, and if user hits cancel again then just exit.

```
Sub SaveWithoutMacro()
Dim objFolder As Object, objFSO As Object

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(ChooseFolder)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=objFolder & "\" & Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - 5) & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51, password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

If objFolder <> False Then Exit SaveWithoutMacro = objFolder


Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True



End Sub

Function ChooseFolder() As String
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String

Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder to save down the copy of this workbook"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = strPath
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

NextCode:
    ChooseFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid the error you have on "Cancel" (coming from the fact that you execute `Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(ChooseFolder)` on an empty string (since `ChooseFolder()` returns empty if the user cancels the action) and at the same time ask him twice - why'd you want to ask them twice? - then you should write your macro like this:

```
Sub SaveWithoutMacro()
    folderPath = ChooseFolder() '<-- ask them to select once
    If folderPath = "" Then '<-- if they clicked cancel once
        MsgBox "You didn't select a folder", vbCritical, "Are you sure?" '<-- message box to inform them
        folderPath = ChooseFolder() '<-- ask them again to select
        If folderPath = "" Then Exit Sub '<-- if again empty, then exit procedure
    End If
    'rest of your save code
```

Comment: i added the code above to my existing code, if the user selects cancel then i get the message box and the the dialog box again. which is exactly what i needed. but now once user has selected the folder the dialog box pop up again, and i don't know why.

Comment: @S.MART did you just copy my code without adapting the rest of yours? The code I gave you can’t pop up the dialog box a second time if you select a folder, I think you’re still calling the old code ‘Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(ChooseFolder)’ right after executing the above.

Answer (score 0):

I dont recommend doing this as it can really annoy the user, but basically you just put it into a `Do Loop` - something like this (untested)

```
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder to save down the copy of this workbook"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = strPath
    Do Until .Show <> -1
        If .SelectedItems(1) <> "" Then GoTo NextCode
    Loop
End With

NextCode:
    ChooseFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
```